# CAN Bus - Is bit stuffing required at EOF and INT?

Tags: can, network

In a `CAN Bus`, to ensure enough transitions to maintain synchronization, `bit stuffing` is used after five consecutive bits of the same polarity.

But we see that the End of Frame `EOF` (7 consecutive `high` bits) and the Intermission `Int` (3 consecutive `high` bits) make a total of 10 consecutive `high` bits( or also called `recessive bits`).

[image: CAN Bus message frame]

Clearly this is at the end of the message and looks like we don't need `bit stuffing`. But I want to know for sure that is `bit stuffing` used here or not.

If not, is there any possibility ever, that there could be a problem due to loss of synchronization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not stuffed. According to [the CAN standard](http://www.bosch-semiconductors.de/media/pdf_1/canliteratur/can2spec.pdf):

> The remaining bit fields of the DATA FRAME or REMOTE FRAME (CRC DELIMITER, ACK FIELD, and END OF FRAME) are of fixed form and not stuffed.

Comment: can you give me a reference?

Comment: www.bosch-semiconductors.de/media/pdf_1/canliteratur/can2spec.pdf

Comment: ok..thanks. and can you answer the second question? `is there any possibility ever, that there could be a problem due to loss of synchronization`

Comment: Re-synchronization would occur at the SOF at the beginning of the next frame. So, no, there shouldn't be any problems